# Different upload speeds on client and server - calculating upload time on the client side

Tags: ftp, upload

Example:

Client (my side) upload speed = 10Mbps

Server upload speed = 5Mbps

If I connect to the server (let's say using FTP) and try to upload 300MB file
The only things to consider is the upload speed (when uploading), am I correct?
How long will it take?

Comment: You gave us to upload numbers we need the download numbers to answer this question.  There are 8 bits in a byte.  You have the capability of transfering around 1.2 MB/sec.  1MB is 1,048,576 bits.  Just do the math.

Comment: Client download = 50Mbps and Server download = 20Mbps

Comment: You would upload the file in less then 4 minutes and 16 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this! I just always thought that only upload speed matters in this case.

Comment: Data transfer from A to B means A is uploading to B ***and*** B is downloading from A. The terms *upload* and *download* are relative, and *which term* you will use to describe a transfer will depend on which computer you are "sitting at". While you call this an *upload*, a network admin sitting at the server will call this a *download* ("This server is downloading data from a client."). *Two faces of the same coin, if you will.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When uploading a file to a ftp-server, the upload speed will most likely be the bottle neck, aka the factor making the transfer slow. As the download speed (at least where I am from) is way better then the upload speed.

example:
Computer A wants to transfer a file to server B
Computer A got a 10 mbit(ps) upload connection (and lets say 50 mbit download, for the sake of ti)
Server A got 100 mbit(ps) upload and 500 mbit(ps) download

The upload on computer A will be the bottle neck. As the server has a 500 mbit download speed.

Meaning:
The upload speed matters on the computer, and the download speed matters on the server